# Are all standard library Python interfaces documented somewhere in one place?

Tags: python

In Python standard library there is a number of implicit interfaces that are expected to be implemented in various cases. For example, coroutines and tasks are "awaitable", meaning they implement the `__await__` method; context managers need to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__`; iterables implement `__next__`; and so on.

Is there a single place where all those interfaces are documented, or does one need to hunt them through the documentation?

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: These are all in the Python “Data Model” section of the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may look for the documentation for the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). All the functions named by you are documentated there, for example [`__await__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__await__) or [`__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__).

To me this is the most fascinating part of the python documentation, because this gives great insight how to max out the features of the python language.